# A simple way to associate an object so to call it method in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a method on some associated object and I want to use it but the associated object needs to have its id set so the method can be working

```
A->B->method()
```

Instead of doing

```
$a = A->find('first');
A->B->id = $a['B'][id'];
A->B->method();
```

Is there a simple way? Because since A belongs to B, why can't I just simple call

```
A->B->method();
```

Let the model relations figure it out

Comment: you should be able to do `A->B->method()` :o, any error raised? Could you post your model files?

Comment: The thing is B->mothod which require that B->id is set. When A->id is set, I have to populate it in some way to set B->id

Comment: what mothod specifically are you talking about? `field()`? `find()`?

Comment: field, which needs to know the id of the object. But How to let B knows its own id when I only know A->id

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, seems like you are trying to find B's specific field from A, if you are setting `Containable` correctly in your model, you can do:

```
A->contain('B.id'); // change B.id to B.whateverfield you are trying to fetch
$a = A->find('first');
echo $a['B']['id']; // change id to whateverfield
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations